# apple developer account dashbaoard

Tags: app-store, iphone-developer-program

In apple developer account dashboard it doesn't contain section of certificates, provisioning profiles
[dashboard with out certificates which appear to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkBom.png)

Comment: You need to click "Join the apple developer program" at the bottom and pay for your licence first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have paid developer account